# Oracle SQL Group by mutiple column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where there are mutiple types of columns example type1,2,3 and 4
I need a sql query where I need to get the count of each type of record based on the date/number of hour i.e `26/01/2010 00`, `26/01/2010 01 am` and so forth

Any help is much appreciated.

```
DATE           TYPE1_RECORDS     TYPE2_RECORDS  TYPE3_RECORDS   TYPE4_RECORDS
26/01/2010 00              2                 1              4               3   
26/01/2010 01              8                 7              2               7   
26/01/2010 02              0                 1              6               1   
26/01/2010 03              0                 4              0               3   
26/01/2010 04              1                 2              9               9   
26/01/2010 05              3                 3              2               0   
26/01/2010 06              6                 7              6               4
```

Comment: SELECT DATE, SUM(TYPE1_RECORDS) etc ... GROUP BY date

Comment: I don't get this. Is what you show the table or the desired result? Please show both. Then you show five titles, but six values. Is 00 to 06 supposed to be a row number only or is it part of the data somehow?

Comment: Your comment to Ruty's answer clarifies this. You should have edited your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic function count(*):

```
select a.*,
count(*) over(partition by <first group of columns>) ,
count(*) over(partition by <second group of columns>) ,
....
from <table> a
```

Comment: May be I was not clear in my question. Basically I have two column in a table date and type; the type has 4 different values so I need to get a report based on date hour, type1, type2, type3, type4 and count of each type

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood your question. In this case you got answer from Thorsten Kettner

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment to Rusty's answer, you want one record by date and hour, so use TO_CHAR to get such string and group by it. You get the counts with conditional aggregates.

```
select 
  to_char(mydate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24') as date_and_hour,
  count(case when type = 1 then 1 end) as type1_count,
  count(case when type = 2 then 1 end) as type2_count,
  count(case when type = 3 then 1 end) as type3_count,
  count(case when type = 4 then 1 end) as type4_count
from mytable
group by to_char(mydate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24')
order by max(mydate), to_char(mydate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24');
```

I use max(mydate) for sorting, which is of course the one date for a date_and_hour, and one could as well take min(mydate) or add mydate to the GROUP BY clause and use it directly then. It's just that we want to sort by date and not by the string (where we would get all 1st Januaries first).